# Use mutable iterator twice

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm trying to write a general function that takes an iterable (or iterator) and iterates it twice, at least once mutably, like:

```
fn f(iter: I)
where I: Iterator<Item = &mut i32> + Clone {
    for i in iter.clone() {
        println!("{}", *i);
    }

    for i in iter.clone() {
        *i += 1;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work because mutable iterators tend not to have clone() implemented, and for just reasons. My real world example is iteration over HashMap values, where `std::collections::hash_map::ValuesMut` is not Clone. Are there any ways to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't obtain the iterator twice from the map?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman because if borrow checker, from each iterator I can obtain a reference to e.g. 1. element, and therefore if I have two iterators I could have two references to the same element, one of which I want mutable.

Comment: @Dekakaruk I think he is referring more to how you can instead pass in `&mut HashMap<K, V>` or [`ValuesMut<'_, K, V>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.ValuesMut.html) and use it more than once to create an iterator.

Comment: @Locke I can't do that because this is only one of possible sources, and actually even here I do hash_map.values_mu().flatten(), which changes types

Comment: If the problem is only code repetition, you can extract it into a function (or closure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you are unable to do this. You will either need to merge them into a single for loop or save the items from the iterator to iterate over them again later.

The closest thing I could come up with is to use `IntoIterator` to require that the argument can be used to make a new iterator multiple times.

```rust
pub fn foo<'a, T>(iter: &'a mut T) 
    where for<'b> &'b mut T: IntoIterator<Item=&'a mut i32> {

    for i in iter.into_iter() {
        println!("{}", *i);
    }

    for i in iter.into_iter() {
        *i += 1;
    }
}


let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert(2, 5);
map.insert(6, 1);
map.insert(3, 4);
    
foo(&mut map.values_mut())
```

However, it seems like much less of a headache for you if you just pass a reference to the entire map.

```rust
pub fn bar<T>(map: &mut HashMap<T, i32>) {
    for i in map.values() {
        println!("{}", *i);
    }

    for i in map.values_mut() {
        *i += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I cannot use the non-generic solution because the iterator will come from various places with different types.

Comment: The generic version does not work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cebd6b4b8244feb3c045a212a7983aef. The iterator is exhausted after the first loop, all further calls to `into_iter` produce an empty iterator.